# awk Compare - GunZip Files:

Tags: awk

Would like to know how to change the below command if the input files are in `*gz` format to compare two files

This command is working

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0;next} {if (!($1 in a)) print $0,a[$1] ; }' OFS=, f22.txt f11.txt>Output_f33.txt
```

where as this command is NOT working

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0;next} {if (!($1 in a)) print $0,a[$1] ; }' OFS=, f22.txt.gz f11.txt.gz>Output_f33.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` works on text based data files. `gz` files are compressed files which means they are no longer in a format that `awk` can parse. You will have to unzip the files and pass them to `awk`. You can do so by saying:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0;next} {if (!($1 in a)) print $0,a[$1] ; }' OFS=, <(gzip -dc f22.txt.gz) <(gzip -dc f11.txt.gz) > Output_f33.txt
```

You can also modify you command to write (broken down to improve readability):

```
awk '
BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}
FNR==NR {a[$1] = $0; next}
!($1 in a){print $0, a[$1]}' <(gzip -dc f22.txt.gz) <(gzip -dc f11.txt.gz) > Output_f33.txt
```